# Request page from same server?

Tags: php, api

I have a website that it consuming it's own API. This means sending a request to itself.

I feel like there might be a way to send a request to a local page quicker than just including the API url.

Right now I'm doing: `file_get_contents("http://domain.com/api/recent")`

These didn't work when I tried it:
`file_get_contents("http://localhost/api/recent")`
 `file_get_contents("http://127.0.0.1/api/recent")`

Comment: if you want to make an HTTP request, you would probably need to use cURL.

Comment: rather, if its on the same site, wouldn't it make more sense just to call the API method directly?

Comment: Usually you would be correct. However, I would like to be able to access the API in the same way en external client would- by querying pages. I feel this would a) introduce less bugs, as there is only 1 entry point for an API functionality, and b) make sure the API is flexible enough. If someone wrote a client in, say, JavaScript, it should be able to be a direct port of the PHP website version.

Comment: depending on how the API is implemented, you can just mimic an external call by setting values into `$_POST`, or `$_GET`, etc. directly, and call the API method. It would be the same thing. If you really insist on making a call, you'll need to use curl

Comment: I understand. My current method works for making the call... file_get_contents performs a standard page query. Will using cURL mean the request never leaves the server? Also, the API might not have a method. One of the API calls is simply a SQL query, sometimes they're just static json. I also want to remain free to change the implementation of the API without breaking all of my pages that use it.

Comment: curl is a tool to make HTTP requests. Even if it's the same site, it'll make a POST, GET, PUT, etc. request to the specified url, much like visiting a page in the browser. If you're making a request to the same server, you will of course need to use localhost/127.0.0.1 instead of the domain name (unless you have the domain name point to itself on the server)

Comment: I switched to using cURL, but it still doesn't work for local requests. If I put in the full domain name, it works, but that's no better than file_get_contents.

Comment: You can run into a potential deadlock at apache level if you make external calls. Imagine you have 10 threads running in apache. 10 users simultaneously hit the page. The first thread is trying to do file_get_contents() or curl_exec(), but it's request is queued by apache as all 10 threads are currently busy. In this way, none of the threads are processed, and everyone gets a timeout error. Are you sure you want to make external calls?

Comment: That's a good point, msound. Can you think of any other ways to do this?

Answer (score 0):

Sorry I can't comment since don't have enough reputation - my 5 cents -

You could easily use the local API by including / requiring the API php file while setting up all the posted / get variables prior to the inclusion. You could cache them if the user sent you important data and then re-set them from cache.

When you call the API with http it is basically slower as it goes through the web server and not through the PHP engine. cheers.